# When I reject a suggested edit from a new user for "harm" and leave an explanation, does the user see the explanation?

Tags: support

When I reject a suggested edit from a <s>new user</s> *veteran SE user* (and moderator on other sites) for "harm" and leave an explanation, does the user see the explanation?

See [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20689/comment56026_20689) on [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20689/12102).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they do not, no notification is presented and no message on or intuitive links from the question make the suggested edit history visible. For all practical purposes the edit is just lost from the suggester's perspective.

Even being very familiar with the SE system (I'm a 100k network wide and a mod on two sites) I was baffled  by what happened to my first edit. I assumed that it must have gotten clobbered by your other edit. I re-submitted it rather than complain about where it went because that was easier, but I was quite confused. **It is possible to find this buried in the activity log in my history, but I had to hunt for it. This should probably be turned into a report on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as this should probably generate a notification or some sort of message if you try to edit again.**

Comment: Considering you are a lot more familliar with SE's function both as a user/moderator and probably you know a thing or two about programming, you'd be a lot better concisely defining the problem. Right now when I click to get the edit history, I only see my one edit, fixing/expanding the 2nd paragraph. I don't see any trace of the comments I've made next to each rejection. It seems to me at least that "expected behavior" would be that they are at least visible to me, if not to you also.

Comment: A problem with the current system, or with me, or both, is that I *thought* I was explaining to somebody, and I presumed it was you. The only other time I see those boxes for text in menus with radio buttons is in voting to close questions or delete answers. Since the interface is the same, I assumed the text box was making my reasons available to others.

Comment: @uhoh Given the interface presented that seems like a reasonable expectation of the system and should be fixed. Our disagreement over what is useful was hobbled and hijacked rather than facilitated by the things we were each presented.

Comment: I feel the same way, and agree 100% that's what resulted. Each time I thought I was explaining to you. But if you can never see the comments I think you are getting, things can really go sideways. In this case I thought you were being weird by just re-making the same edit several times and ignoring my explanations.

Comment: There are a number of MSE requests for this; characteristic is https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142780/help-users-discover-and-learn-from-the-results-of-their-edit-suggestions