# How does one report an offensive suggested edit?

Tags: support

on suggested edit https://space.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/27923

for question [Are there any long term storable sources of vitamin C?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/54559/are-there-any-long-term-storable-sources-of-vitamin-c)

There is a VERY offensive "suggested edit" which adds quote

> Power-tripping moderator dυmβfυcκs: stop rejecting valid edit suggestions and please correct the fυcκing typo in the previous paragraph: "Vitamic" -> "Vitamin".

by so-called "anonymous user".

What is the correct way to report an offensive action such as this.
Yes, i could just reject the edit (and correct my simple typo), but I see no way of actually reporting the offensive action.
(Surely this must be a registered user, a drive-by viewer does not have edit suggestion ability, do they?)

Comment: I think this is really the only way to report. We (mods) don't have a way of investigating that, but we could raise it to CMs for them to investigate.

Comment: It does look like truly drive-by anonymous users can in fact make edit suggestions: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/#:~:text=The%20Stack%20Exchange%20engine%20draws,anonymous%20users%20to%20edit%20content.&text=The%20Stack%20Exchange%20engine%20draws%20inspiration%20from%20a%20number%20of%20sources.,-We%20continue%20to

Comment: That being the case, I'm not super confident there's a lot CMs can do.

Comment: @called2voyage Thank you for looking at this. I find it silly that one need not even register to post a suggested edit, but at least it is easy to clean the slate.

Comment: Funny thing--I looked back at the suggested edit history and every single one in the queue is just the user complaining about their edit being rejected. I don't see an original good faith edit. I wonder if they tried to change just that word and the system automatically rejected it for being too small of a change. If so kind of amusing they're shouting into the void against an automated response.

Comment: @called2voyage do you mean something like this? [When I reject a suggested edit from a new user for “harm” and leave an explanation, does the user see the explanation?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/860/12102)

Answer (score 3):

Someone is frustrated and lashing out. Obviously they're doing so inappropriately, but what purpose would reporting them serve? If you had some kind of ongoing working relationship with the person, their behavior would be unacceptable, obviously, but in this case the thing to do is to fix the typo and count yourself lucky you have better things to get worked up about than that user does.